# How do I get colab to access a folder in github repository to work on the files inside?

Tags: python-3.x, github, google-colaboratory

So I want to use colab to work on some files I have, but it is stored on github. I would prefer not to download the files or put it in google drive (low storage). How can I get colab to access a folder in my repo, in such a way as to loop through the files inside or something, and replace them too?

like how would my new code look like in colab? P.S this was the code I used when working directly form my HDD.

```
import os
for a in os.listdir(folder):
if a.endswith('.txt'):
print('1')
```

Comment: You could clone the repo? Something like `git clone <repo url>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store it in OneDrive. To do that, you'll first need to authenticate and then pass the location of the file you're after, by using the OneDrive REST API. The details on how to do that are documented on the [OneDrive's SDK for Python](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-python) GitHub page with some examples to get you started.

You can also use the `resquest` library :

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/README.rst')
>>> 'Requests:' in r.text
True
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> r = requests.get('https://raw.github.com/kennethreitz/requests/master/README.rst')
>>> 'Requests:' in r.text
True
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
>>> print r.text
Requests: HTTP for Humans
=========================


.. image:: https://travis-ci.org/kennethreitz/requests.png?branch=master
[... etc. ...]
```

There is also the git library to create object model access to your git repository. You can find a tutorial in that [link](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).